# Instalación de Servicio Web

Tags: webservice

estoy tratando de instalar un servicio web a un servidor, pero me rechaza la instalación, de casualidad alguno conoce algún comando para instalarlo desde el CMD. Se los agradecería muchisimo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ruta del InstallUtil.exe + Ruta del Instalador del Servicio de Windows
"c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneradorXML.exe"

Comment: Esto es complemento de tu pregunta cierto?